# Julia - ARM Remez code eval() world age mismatch

Tags: julia, eval, expression-evaluation

I'm still trying to compile the original ARM Remez code Julia 0.4 under modern dialect v1.9.3 and it is putting up some resistance. It now compiles OK but fails at runtime. There are two distinct problems one is fundamental: world age mismatch "function is too new" and way beyond my present understanding and the other is probably trivial but I can't see the wood for the trees. This is the really hard one. It fails to @eval sin(x) internally.

```
martin@martin-virtual-machine:~/Downloads$ julia ARMremez.jl 0 1 5 0 'sin(x)'
   Resolving package versions...
   No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.9/Project.toml`
   No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.9/Manifest.toml`
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching (::var"#53#54")(::BigFloat)
The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 33517, while current world is 33518.

Closest candidates are:
 (::var"#53#54")(::Any) (method too new to be called from this world context.)
 @ Main none:1

Stacktrace:
 [1] (::var"#func#49"{var"#53#54"})(x::BigFloat)
  @ Main ~/Downloads/ARMremez.jl:1229
 [2] ratfn_leastsquares(f::var"#func#49"{var"#53#54"}, xvals::Vector{BigFloat}, n::Int64, d::Int64, w::var"#47#51")
  @ Main ~/Downloads/ARMremez.jl:348
 [3] ratfn_minimax(f::var"#func#49"{var"#53#54"}, interval::Tuple{BigFloat, BigFloat}, n::Int64, d::Int64, w::var"#47#51")
  @ Main ~/Downloads/ARMremez.jl:819
 [4] main()
  @ Main ~/Downloads/ARMremez.jl:1253
 [5] top-level scope
  @ ~/Downloads/ARMremez.jl:1330
  in expression starting at /home/martin/Downloads/ARMremez.jl:1330

 # the relevant sourcecode after my modification is below f is the parameter 'sin(x)' from the commandline

f = eval(Meta.parse("x -> " * argwords[5]))

# Wrap the user-provided function with a function of our own. This
# arranges to detect silly FP values (inf,nan) early and diagnose
# them sensibly, and also lets us log all evaluations of the
# function in case you suspect it's doing the wrong thing at some
# special-case point.
@noinline function func(x)
    y = f(x)
    @debug("f", x, " -> ", y)
    if !isfinite(y)
        error("f(" * string(x) * ") returned non-finite value " * string(y))
    end
    return y
end
```

I have tried adding the incantation @noinline as recommended in [@eval world age mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272550/julia-eval-world-age-missmatch) but still got a very similar error (I'm probably doing it wrong). I can work out from the stack trace that the failure is in executing the wrapped implementation of evaluating the user supplied function 'sin(x)' from the command line, but after that I am stuck. I find it amazing that the environment can magic up BigFloat sin(x) to order inside the already running code.

The other is too trivial to start a thread about and must be really obvious to anyone well experienced with Julia but it certainly isn't obvious to me. I still haven't got the hang of declaring typed arrays in Julia 1.9.3 The specific line that I can't get past this time is

```
# original line in v0.4 code
# a = Array(BigFloat, n+1)

# my best guess according to the syntax tree
a = Array{BigFloat}{undef,n+1}
```

I tried lots of of other combos but got precisely nowhere. I can declare an array that is initialised with values OK but I cannot figure out how to declare a 1D array of length N :(
A lamentable failure on my part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Array construction

The easy question first: you almost have it, it just needs ordinary parentheses for the last part: `a = Array{BigFloat}(undef,n+1)`. One way to remember it is curly braces `{ ... }` are used for type specification, and parentheses `( ... )` make a function call. So here we're specifying an `Array` containing type `BigFloat` (which goes in curlies because it's a type), and we want to call the constructor for that Array (so parentheses because it's a call).
Or you can just use `zeros` which you might find simpler to remember: `zeros(BigFloat, n+1)`.

##### World age issues

The `@noinline` suggestion in the linked question is from a comment that's mentioned as not working, the actual solution suggested there is `invokelatest`, as given in the answer there. To implement that here, you can change

```
function func(x)
    y = f(x)
```

in the original code to

```
function func(x)
    y = invokelatest(f, x)
```

and similarly also change

```
    function wrapped_weight(x,y)
        ww = w(x,y)
```

to

```
    function wrapped_weight(x,y)
        ww = invokelatest(w, x,y)
```

**However**, this changes every call to these functions to be a dynamic runtime-determined call, which can slow down the program - it looks like `f` and `w` are being called from a main `while true` loop, so this could be a lot of slowdown.

If you find that this makes it unworkably slow, you can instead move the first half of the `main` function ([these lines](https://github.com/ARM-software/optimized-routines/blob/da55ef9510a53822b5706c61ad97795828999c80/auxiliary/remez.jl#L1204-L1248)) to be outside `main` in global scope. Putting the `eval`s in global scope makes it so that `f` and `w` are created in the same world age as `ratfn_leastsquares` and other functions, so should avoid the world age problem without needing `invokelatest`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I still can't quite get it past the next logjam which is an array of intialised to zero Tuples of BigFloat. Original code and my best guess follow: 
#    best = fill((BigFloat(0), Array((BigFloat,BigFloat),0)), n, 2)
    best = Array{Tuple{BigFloat,BigFloat}}(Tuple(BigFloat(0),BigFloat(0)),n)  and also 
#    extrema = Tuple((BigFloat, BigFloat), 0)
    extrema = Tuple{{BigFloat, BigFloat}, 0} I thought this now followed the rules but alas Julia 1.9.3 thinks otherwise.

Comment: Would you like to open a [chat room here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new) or a Github repo with your current version of the code, so we can discuss this more easily?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It isn't unworkably slow at all. The main delay is from compiling it. I will set up a Github repo for it when I next get stuck. I realised that I could examine the existing Library to deduce the correct declarations shortly after posting my reply. I now have the original ARM code fully working, validated and tested on 1.9.3. My next aim is to make it able to handle polynomials where the terms are in x^2 rather than x. I'm bound to get stuck again but I am finally beginning to get the hang of when to use each sort of brackets (),{}.[] in Julia